# There are any Event scheduler alternate in mysql Linux hosting

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with Event Scheduler in mysql, because my Cloud Linux Hosting doesn't allow Event scheduler status to **Enable** .

When I was going to enable i get this error with query-> `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler="ON"`

> #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

I had contact to customer support but they saying, we cant support This features.

This is my Event Scheduler Mysql Query->

```
CREATE EVENT new_event1 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND 
STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 10 SECOND) 
DO INSERT INTO earning_money(uid, amount) 
   VALUES ('1', '150');
```

There are any alternate way to do this. And I listen about CronJob in php but I don't have any idea about it.

Please Guide me anyone.

Answer (score 0):

*/10 * * * * /path/to/your/script/script.php

it will run every 10 minutes

Comment: Can you expand on this please?

Comment: can i create multiple with multiple value

Comment: but i have multiple query to run -> INSERT INTO earning_money(uid, amount) VALUES ('1','150')

Comment: also you can create shell script include your mysql queryes and then run following: */10 * * * * sh script.sh

Comment: please do one favour to me, this is my query,     INSERT INTO earning_money(uid, amount) VALUES ('1','150'); this value will be fixed and count from date coulm timestamp to 24hrs

Comment: i mean run this same query with same value on every 24 hrs

Comment: * 0 * * * sh script.sh